# Treat parameter as an empty string or null if user did not enter any value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
SET @email = NULL

SELECT * FROM empTable
WHERE email = ISNULL(@email, '')
```

`@email` will take input from the user. The problem is, the `email` column in the table can be an empty string or `null` (or an email).

If the user doesn't enter any value, it should return all `Employees` with either `NULL` or empty `string` email.

I have tried to following but it didn't work too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM empTable
WHERE email = ISNULL(@email, '') OR email = ISNULL(@email, NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM empTable
WHERE email = ISNULL(@email, '') OR (email IS NULL AND @email IS NULL)
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM empTable
WHERE ISNULL(email,'') = ISNULL(@email, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

if email is then condition after second OR will be considered

if email is present then first curly brackets will be considered

```
SELECT * FROM empTable
WHERE (email=@email) or (@email is null OR email = ISNULL(@email, ''))
```

Comment: It doesn't work, now if the input is `NULL`, it will just return EVERYTHING

Comment: `If the user doesn't enter any value, it should return all Employees`

Comment: it should return "all Employees with either NULL or empty string email"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

IF @email has value then corresponding row will retrieve from DB; else second condition will execute which will retrieve email with NULL and empty string.

```
SELECT * 
FROM empTable
WHERE email = ISNULL(@email, '') OR (email IS NULL and email = '')
```

Comment: Thanks for upvote+downvote. Hope you got the output.